# Curity Identity server attemps to allocate too much memory

Tags: docker, curity

I've tried to start a curity identity server on my local machine using docker. I have followed their documentation ([reference](https://curity.io/resources/learn/run-curity-docker/)), but the server won't start. The message I get is the following:

```
2023-02-24T12:45:16:514+0000 WARN    {main} se.curity.identityserver.app.ConfDStarter - Configuration service could not be stopped (code 134)
2023-02-24T12:45:16:516+0000 INFO    {main} se.curity.identityserver.app.ConfDStarter - Configuration Service has been started.
2023-02-24T12:45:16:741+0000 WARN    {main} se.curity.identityserver.app.ConfDStarter - The Configuration Service halted unexpectedly with code 134: Unknown error See the log file '/opt/idsvr/var/log/confsvc.log' for more details
2023-02-24T12:45:16:742+0000 INFO    {main} se.curity.identityserver.app.DelegatableShutdownSwitch - Server being shutdown by switch called 'ConfDStarter'
2023-02-24T12:45:16:743+0000 WARN    {main} se.curity.identityserver.app.ConfDStarter - Will not start Configuration phase 2 because the Configuration Service did not start successfully.
2023-02-24T12:45:16:876+0000 INFO    {main} se.curity.identityserver.localization.ReloadableMessageProviderMap - Reloading messages Map
2023-02-24T12:45:16:930+0000 INFO    {main} se.curity.identityserver.app.GlobalServerShutdownSwitch - Shutdown event triggered
```

The log file `/opt/idsvr/var/log/confsvc.log` contains the following:

```
sys_alloc: Cannot allocate 34359738368 bytes of memory (of type "db_tabs").
Daemon died status=134
```

That's 32GB! Why does Curity try to allocate so much memory, when the [minimum hardware requirements are just 4GB?](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/system-admin-guide/system-requirements.html)

Edit: As requested, here's my system information:

```
OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X (16) @ 3.700GHz
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 570X
Memory: 24063MiB
```

Comment: As the initial response indicates, the system details (OS, versions of software packages, etc.) are often quite important in debugging issues like these. Please try to include as many relevant ones as you can think of in future questions.

Comment: I've updated my initial post with my system info. That said, I don't think they should be relevant, since I pass the minimum system requirements, and I'm running it via docker, so versions *should* not matter

Comment: Are you doing anything special with configuration, such as supplying a backup XML file? Or are you just running the default (ubuntu) docker image, with default arguments? Could you try downloading the Linux 64 bit build from the developer portal, and running that directly on your Manjaro host OS, and see if that makes a difference? Then have a look at the `confsvc.log` file to see if that tells you anything.

Comment: Just the default docker image, no configuration at all. I've posted my logs in my main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late to the game, but..

One of the components used internally by the Curity Identity Server may try to allocate a lot of memory on startup if the "open files" limit in the system is large.

It seems that the Docker images for some Linux distros have a very large default. For example, I get the following in a Curity container in RHEL 9:

```
> ulimit -n
1073741816
```

Setting that to a reasonable value (1024 is a common default) in the container before running Curity should solve the issue.